# DevExpress gridView Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, devexpress

I am working on asp web form project with entity framework. I have two entities (users and roles) and I want to implement the following behaviour:
The gridView must display the roles of one user. 
What I did so far is to display all the roles.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid"  runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientInstanceName="grid" 
    KeyFieldName="Id" OnDataBinding="grid_DataBinding" DataSourceID="RoleDataSource" EnableTheming="True" Theme="BlackGlass">
    <ClientSideEvents RowDblClick="function(s, e) {
        s.StartEditRow(e.visibleIndex);}" />
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="ID" FieldName="Id" VisibleIndex="0">
            <EditFormSettings  Visible="false"/>
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Role Name" FieldName="name" VisibleIndex="1" >
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>


    </Columns>
    <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="true" AllowSelectByRowClick="True" AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="True" ConfirmDelete="True" />

        <SettingsEditing Mode="PopupEditForm"/>

        <SettingsText CommandUpdate="Ajouter/Modifier" PopupEditFormCaption="Ajouter/Modifier" />
        <SettingsPopup>
            <EditForm AllowResize="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </SettingsPopup>
    </dx:ASPxGridView>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="RoleDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=AccountModelContainer" 
    DefaultContainerName="AccountModelContainer" EntitySetName="RoleSet" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [the `Where` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your EntityDataSource.

You would add a property like this to your EntityDataSource declaration:

```
Where="name = @name"
```

(or maybe you would filter on "ID", whichever works for your application)

And then add a `WhereParameters` section to your markup inside the EntityDataSource:

```
<WhereParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="userNameTB" DbType="String" 
        DefaultValue="testUser" Name="name" PropertyName="Text" />
</WhereParameters>
```

Note that this example assumes you have a TextBox names "userNameTB" that has the username you want to filter on.  However, you can use any of [the `<asp:Parameter>` controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.aspx):

- ControlParameter
- FormParameter
- SessionParameter
- RouteParameter
- CookieParameter
- QueryStringParameter
- ProfileParameter

So your final code would look something like this:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="RoleDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString=""
    name=AccountModelContainer" DefaultContainerName="AccountModelContainer" 
    EntitySetName="RoleSet" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" 
    EnableUpdate="True" Where="name = @name">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="userNameTB" DbType="String" 
            DefaultValue="testUser" Name="name" PropertyName="Text" />
    </WhereParameters>
```